# Grouping SQL Server backup files together for restoration

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, smo

I have a SQL Server database that is creating full backups once a week, differential backups once a day, and transaction log backups hourly. These are being FTP'd to another box, where I would like a .NET app (which I am writing) to pick them up and restore them into a working database.

Every hour when a new transaction log file comes in, I want to find the appropriate full backup file, differential backup file, and other log txn files for that day use them to restore the database.

I can do all this fine using the [SQL Server Management Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) .NET interfaces.

The issues is that this machine will have several weeks of backup files on it so I need a way to group them together appropriately. What is the best way to do this?

The names of the files themselves do contain timestamp data, e.g.

> MyDatabase_FULL_20150208_000001.bak

but I would prefer to not to parse file names to get date/time info out.

The SMO objects do offer a way to read in the file and get header information out, one of which is the data/time the backup was created.

That's okay I guess but I know that SQL Server has a way to use the [LSN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190411%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) metadata within the backup files themselves to group them together. I just don't know how it works or if the SMO API gives you access to it.

If anyone has any insight into an easy and/or reliable way to group these files all together that would be great.

Comment: Is `msdb` getting FTP'd with your other db backups?  `msdb` should have all the pertinent backup info you need (LSN's, backup start/finish dates, file name(s), etc.)  Restore `msdb` first, then you can query it to get all the data you need for the other db's.

Comment: Not currently FTPing msdb, but it would appear that you can use the RESTORE HEADERONLY command on the files themselves to the LSN data.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to access the LSN through SMO. A quick google brings me to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.readbackupheader.aspx) page. It has no C# example but there is one for VB.NET or PowerShell.

```powershell
$srv = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("(local)")
$res = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore
$backup = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup
$backup.Devices.AddDevice("C:\AdventureWorks2012Backup.bak", [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DeviceType]::File)
$backup.Database = "AdventureWorks2012"
$backup.Action = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupActionType]::Database
$backup.Initialize = $TRUE
$backup.SqlBackup($srv)

$res.Devices.AddDevice("C:\AdventureWorks2012Backup.bak", [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DeviceType]::File)
$dt = $res.ReadBackupHeader($srv)

foreach($r in $dt.Rows)
{
   foreach ($c in $dt.Columns)
   {
      Write-Host $c "=" $r[$c]
   }
}
```

To link the LSNs together you need to:

1. Identify the latest Full Backup: The backup with the highest CheckpointLSN
2. Identify the latest Differential Backup: The backup with the highest CheckpointLSN where the DatabaseBackupLSN equals the CheckpointLSN of the Full Backup.
3. Identify the first Transaction Log backup to be restored: The backup with a FirstLSN lower than the differential backup and a LastLSN higher than the differential backup.
4. Chain all the other missing Transaction Log backups together: The next backup is the backup where the FirstLSN equals the LastLSN of the previous backup.

**EDIT**

[Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190729(v=sql.105).aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2013/05/22/how-do-i-map-a-differential-transaction-log-backup-to-its-full-backup-without-using-msdb.aspx) is some more information about the LSN chain.

Comment: Great info, thank you. Couple of questions. How would I identify the last txn log backup based on the LSN? Also, can you reference a Microsoft document that explains how the LSNs relate in the way you describe. I'm sure you're correct, but I need to back this up with official documentation.

Comment: I updated my post with some sources about LSNs. The last backup is the transaction log backup with the highest LastLSN.

Comment: Great, thank you. Another question: let's say that I have the last five days worth of backups and I want to restore up to the end of day 3. I apply the full backup and day 3's differential, but how would I know when to stop applying transaction log backups (i.e. stop at day 4)? Would I grab the FirstLSN and LastLSN of day 4's differential backup (call them d4_F and d4_L) and stop when I got to a log backup where FisrtLSN <= d4_F &&  LastLSN >= d4_L?